# How to save user when saving a form using post within Class-Based Views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Currently the form instance is being saved but the user who filled out the information isn't being saved when I save this form. I am wondering how to grab the user and have it be added to the creation of the new form object.

```
class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Object
    template_name = 'ui/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'objects'
    form_class = OrderForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            order_type = form.cleaned_data.get('order_type')
            price = form.cleaned_data.get('price')
            **user = request.user**
            messages.success(request, f'Your order has been placed.')
        return redirect('account')
```

Comment: You've got the user there, `user = request.user` so just put that where you want it? I assume an order has a FK to a user?

Comment: Does the user need to be saved in the `Object` model?

Comment: @Mugoma yes it needs to be saved in the object model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add more info before saving a form, you can use the parameter `commit=False`

**views.py**

```
class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, ListView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user ## Assuming that the relevant field is named user, it will save the user accessing the form using request.user
            obj.save()
            ...
        return redirect('account')  ## this should be indented if it is to work only on successfully saving the form
```

Comment: Your answer is closest to what OP wants but your code will not work. You need to use a variable to keep what `form.save(commit=False)` is returning, like `obj=form.save(commit=False)`. Then you can use `obj.user=request.user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the user object from `User` model of django and save the object using `save` method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Object
    template_name = 'ui/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'objects'
    form_class = OrderForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) #fetch the user object
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            order_type = form.cleaned_data.get('order_type')
            price = form.cleaned_data.get('price')
            user.save() #saves/updates the user
            messages.success(request, f'Your order has been placed.')
        return redirect('account')
```

Comment: If `request.user` exists, then it's already a `User` instance and you're adding an extra database query here for no good reason.